# Excel VBA Copy a Cell's Value to overwrite it's formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell that has a formula, it shows a word, I want to be able to edit that cell if I want. The problem is if I attempt, it shows the formula, I want to create a button next to it that will allow the formula to be replaced by the word it is showing. I thought this script would do it, but obviously not.

Can someone show me where I went wrong?

```
Sub Edit_Nonconformity()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 40).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 40).Value
End Sub
```

I thought if I copied the "Value" of the cell and pasted it back on there, it would overwrite the script, at least that is how I thought it would work.

Basically the formula is pulling from another sheet, so it uses a standard formula, what I want to do is with a push of a button have it change the cell from formula showing said text to an editable text if you wish to edit the cell.

does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It will work as you mentioned. Are you referring to the right workbook or the right cell? Which cell has the formula? $AN$2 [which is Cells(2, 40)] or $B$40 [Which is Cells(40,2)]?

Comment: Are you telling me that I got the numbers mixed up? Yup, I did... can I put my head through the table? I actually got code correct, but the placement was all wrong... dang it! I hate being Dyslexic at times.

Comment: No :) I am asking you which cell has the formula? AN2 or B40 or some other. EDIT: I see that you got it :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells(2, 3) = Cells(2, 2)` sets the result of the formula in C2 = the text in B2.